# codeigniter captcha not showing in iis

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, captcha

I have a codeigniter website and I use captcha, my captcha worked in last server but in new server not creating and not shoing captcha
I Use windows server 2016 standard, IIS 10< PHP 7.0 and Codeigniter 3.1

```
function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('us_login') == TRUE)
        {   
            redirect ('dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['captcha'] = $this->_create_captcha();
            $this->load->view('login', $data);  
        }
    }



function _create_captcha()
{
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        // numeric random number for captcha
        $random_number = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,8);
        // setting up captcha config
        $vals = array(
            'word' => $random_number,
            'img_path' => './captcha/',
            'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
            'img_width' => 280,
            'img_height' => 45,
            'expiration' => 7200
            );
        $data['captcha'] = create_captcha($vals);
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaWord',$data['captcha']['word']);
        return $data['captcha'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in [this](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63814.html) is asnwer for you question.

In Codeigniter path `system/helpers/captcha_helper.php`

you most change fixed `captcha_helper`

```
-                   if (($rand_index = unpack('C', $bytes[$byte_index++])) > $rand_max)
+                   list(, $rand_index) = unpack('C', $bytes[$byte_index++]);
+                   if ($rand_index > $rand_max)
```

Comment: I fixed this problem with enable extension=php_gd2.dll in php.ini file